# asp.net mvc throw 404 from controller factory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, castle-windsor, handle

We throw a 404 from the factory if we can't find the controller in the container. However this results in the standard error page not our custom error page. It's like throwing a 404 here bypasses normal error handling. Is this expected?

Comment: What does the `<customErrors>` section in the web.config look like?

Comment: Just have custom errors on. I just want it to resolve to the error.cshtml in shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `defaultRedirect="Home/Error"` to the `<customErrors>` section and make sure you have an action method named `Error` on some controller, in this sample I used `Home`. I tried throwing a 404 from a custom `ControllerFactory` with this setup and I got the expected error view.